# How to prevent a Windows 10 application from detecting other applications

Tags: windows

I'm having an issue that the application I'm trying to run is detecting other applications (Recording Software, False Detection bla bla bla which is really annoying) and it asks me to close other applications before running.

---

Are there anyway to prevent that application from detecting? Or limiting its access? Or create an application to run it and limiting its access?

---

If there aren't any ways it's okay. I can still use a vm (but it's my last option because it consumes lots of computer resources)

---

- I'm using Windows 10
- The application I'm trying to run is .exe (written in C++)

Answer (score 0):

Application detection is usually implemented by looking for a specific window class with `FindWindowEx` or by using a [named mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects). It is also possible to look at all the running processes and comparing the .exe names.

Window detection is limited to each desktop. Switching to another user in a new session will allow you to bypass this detection. [Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) would also work.

Mutex detection can be per-session or machine global.

Process detection is usually machine global unless they specifically check the session id.